# WebStorm / PhpStorm auto require for CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, webstorm, commonjs

WebStorm auto-import for ES6 modules works great. Is it possible to have auto-require for CommonJS modules?

Here is my test case:

```js
// file es6.js
export default {
  foo: () => console.log('foo')
}
```

```js
// file common.js
module.exports = {
  bar: () => console.log('bar')
};
```

```js
// file index.js
import {foo} from './es6';
const {bar} = require('./common');

foo(); // 3
bar(); // 4
```

When I copy and paste lines 3,4 to a new file, I got

```js
// file index2.js
import {foo} from "./es6";

foo();
bar();
```

`foo` function was auto-imported, but `bar` wasn't. Is it possible to auto-require `bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-import is only supported for ES6 modules.
To create missing `require()` calls, use quick fixes available on `Alt+Enter`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case PHPStorm suggests 'Insert 'import {bar} from "./common"'. Should I somehow configure a project for PHPStorm to suggest _require_ instead of _import_?

Comment: Please make sure that coding assistance for Node.js is enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM** and **JavaScript | Node.js | Missing require() statement** inspection is turned on in **Settings | Editor | Inspections**

Comment: Enabling _Conding assistance for Node.js_ helped, thanks!